# How to set border style

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.3, richtextarea

I am wondering is there an optimal way to set border (CSS like) for RichTextArea directly?;

I tried to use Formatter but it doesn't contain required methods :(

I'm using GWT 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of achieving it.

You can use the following

```
getElement().setAttribute( "name", "value" );
```

Here provide CSS attribute name you want to modify and provide the value.

```
getElement().setClassName( "className" );
getElement().addClassName( "className" );
```

Here provide the CSS classname( it can be any name). Use the same className in your CSS file and do all the manipulation you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the CSS settings to your gwt-objects

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could extended the frame from GWT's frame with a method that sets the border:

```
public void setFrameBorder(Integer border) {
    getFrameElement().setFrameBorder(border);
}
```

Comment: where getFrameElement() method comes from? Give more details please

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be to use the embedded methods inside GWT, which are:

- [setBorderStyle(BorderStyle style)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#setBorderStyle-com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.BorderStyle-)
- [setBorderWidth(double value, Style.Unit unit)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#setBorderWidth-double-com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit-)
- [setBorderColor(String color)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#setBorderColor-java.lang.String-)

from the [GWT Style](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html) class.

Here is an example:

```
HTMLPanel htmlPanel= new HTMLPanel("TestPanel");
htmlPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID); // DOTTED, NONE ...
htmlPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(0.5, Unit.PX);
htmlPanel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderColor("#DD05FF");
```

Here your `htmlPanel` would have a purple, solid border of 0.5 pixel wide.